# Avoid race condition using RDBMS transaction

Tags: microservices, message-queue, distributed-system, distributed-computing, rdbms

I am working on design of a distributed system which will process some events. For simplicity lets say, multiple instance of same service will be consuming from same queue, every message will have a id for which the event has generated and it will read the current value of it from the DB and increment it by 1 and update in DB.
The service has a SQL with transaction;
Pseudo code:

```
.
.
.
start transaction
   state <- read the state from db for the said id
   count <- read the count from db for the said id
   if no record found
       state <- 'QUEUED'
       count <- 0
   if state == 'QUEUED' and count == 5
       state <- 'INPROGRESS'
   if state == 'QUEUED' and count < 5
       count <- count + 1
   update the DB for the said id
commit
.
.
.
```

Consider, current DB state at 9:59:00:00 am

```
-------------------
id | count | state 
-------------------
0  | 4     | QUEUED
-------------------
```

There are 2 instances of the service are available and there is one event with id = 1 at 9:59:20:00 am;
If the Service(instance-1) takes 3 second to make the updation in DB then at 9:59:23:00 am DB state will be

```
-------------------
id | count | state 
-------------------
0  | 4     | QUEUED
1  | 1     | QUEUED
-------------------
```

Now there are two events with id = 2 at the same time or very close interval. Say,

```
Event-1 at 10:00:00:00 am  
Event-2 at 10:00:00:50 am
```

Service instance-1 takes 3 second to process Event-1 and Service instance-2 takes 2 second to process Event-2.

Will this produce any inconsistency, or very time in such scenario it will produce same result (At 10:00:06:00 am for id=2, value=2, state=QUEUED)

```
-------------------
id | count | state 
-------------------
0  | 4     | QUEUED
1  | 1     | QUEUED
2  | 2     | QUEUED
-------------------
```

To handle this kind of race condition any other good design pattern available, like locking

Thanks in advance for considering this problem statement

Comment: I'm not following your example scenario: "Now there are two events with id = 2" is particularly puzzling.  Why are there two events with the same Id?

Comment: Hi @JimmyJames, so there are publisher based on some logic it will generate events. Now those events can have new id or existing id. Now my example for id = 2 two events are generated

Comment: OK, I think events are about something with id = 2.  When I first read this, I thought you were saying the event's id was 2.  You might want to clarify that in the question.  I'm now unclear how you end up with 2 as the value.  Wouldn't both instances find 0 rows in the db?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, I have updated it

Comment: Or is 2 the desired answer in that scenario?

Comment: Right, that is my ask. As per my understanding after completion of both in the DB will have count 1.  2 is desire

Comment: As the transaction is not useful, I am thinking to acquire a update lock, but how it will behave if the id is not there (Like in the example 2 is a new id). Can you please suggest some good solution for this

Comment: In a good database system one of the transactions will **fail** and you are supposed to repeat it from the beginning. However, getting this right means carefully reading the documentation, and possibly fiddling with isolation modes and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice pattern for this kind of problem that uses an optimistic locking approach.  You don't need anything special to implement it.  Just a uniqueness constraint on the id column and a `where` clause on your update SQL.

So first, by putting a uniqueness constraint on the id column, you prevent two rows from being inserted with the same id.  So in your scenario, both event processors see no rows.  Each will then attempt to insert one.  Due to the uniqueness constraint, only one can succeed.  The handler with the failed insert will need to catch the error and retry.

The second part of this approach is that when you do find an existing row, you should add the current `count` to the where clause.  For example, if you find a row and the count is one, your update should be something like:

```
UPDATE status
SET count = <count + 1>
WHERE id = <id>
  AND count = <count>
```

The `AND` clause is the trick.  If another processor has incremented the count, the update won't fail but no rows will be changed.  You simply check the updated row count after you execute the statement.  If 0 rows are updated, you retry the update after getting the new count.

I like this approach because it avoids the complexity and costs of pessimistic locking.  It's also fairly easy to understand, IMO.

Addendum:

There's another approach I would also consider in your situation.  Instead updating the table in place, you instead insert a new record for each transaction.  You then no longer store a count column but rather use a `count()` query to determine whether you have 5 transactions.  Note that in this case, it will be difficult to prevent more than 5 transactions from being processed and written to the DB.

The advantage with this is that there is no locking required and the sequence and timing of the processing can be easily observed from the entries.

Comment: Thank you, it is fairly a simple, easy to understand and effective solution.

Comment: Do you have anything else in mind that I can explore for the same

Comment: This is generally how I would do it.  The only issue that can come up with this is if you have a very high volume of transactions hitting the same id, you could have a starvation situation.  But given 5 max updates, you are done, that's not really an issue, unless there's some other constraint that you haven't mentioned.  There are other possible solutions, but I find they can be difficult to get right and often come with performance challenges.

Comment: Mostly this will solve the issue, but if you spell out others I will have a look and learn something. One more thing is there any workaround if I failed to meet the uniqueness criteria, like planning to follow SCD type-3, so the primary key will be in combination of timestamp and retrieve based on sorting of ts.

Comment: *"if you have a very high volume of transactions hitting the same id, you could have a starvation situation"* - Exactly! If there are 10 events/messages per hour, this can work fine. But if there are 100 000 events/messages per hour, this can lead to huge starvation. This is the reason why *sequences* are used. You request the sequence *once* and get a *block* of IDs, e.g. 1000 IDs, and there is *guarantee* that no other process will use them.

Comment: @mentallurg I understand your line of thinking here but I think the Ids are coming from somewhere else.  The problem, as I understand it, isn't a race condition on the id generation but rather the updates to the count.

Comment: @JimmyJames: *"the Ids are coming from somewhere else"* - No.. The author says that 2 service instances want to use *the same* next ID and wants to resolve this conflict.

Comment: @mentallurg, the id here is not event identifier. For a specific id the event has generated. Lets say id is emp_id, for that an event has generated

Comment: @SiddharthaSadhukhan: "*For a specific id the event has generated.*" - What do you mean? How can event generate an ID?

Comment: @mentallurg There's something that has an id and then there are up to 5 events processed on before its status goes to 'INPROGRESS'.  What the ids refer to isn't explained.

Comment: Lets say id means emp_id and that employ has changed the address, for that the event has generated. Nothing has to be done until the employ change the address 5 time. This analogy just to explain it

Comment: @SiddharthaSadhukhan: OK. Now it is more clear. Then use emp_id as ID. Why do you want to use an additional ID - 1, 2, 3... ?

Comment: @SiddharthaSadhukhan I added another option in case you didn't notice.

Comment: @JimmyJames, sorry I missed it, but it will not be useful as the count is hard constraint. Preferring type-3, so that if anything unforeseen situation occur then we will be at a better position to evaluate.

Comment: Is there a possibility of more than 5 events firing for a single id?

Comment: Yes, it may occur

Comment: So what happens if a handler processes a 6th event?  Is it a major issue or do you just want to discard the results?

Comment: No, it will act as a group. When there is 5 event it will generate an event for another service. And new event for same id will start from count 0

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches, depending on what database you use, and depending on how much implementation efforts you can afford.

1. You can use *sequences*. Databases like Oracle, MS SQL Server and PostgreSQL support them. Every time you call *nextval*, it gives you a next number. This guaranties that every time you will get a new ID. To improve performance, you can configure sequence to generate IDs in block of let say 100 elements. Thus on the 1st call one services will get ID=1 (and can use IDs 1..100 without requesting the sequence again), the 2nd service will get ID=101 (and can use IDs 101..200 without requesting the sequence again). The IDs in database will then not necessarily correspond to the insert time and may look like 1, 2, 101, 3, 102, 103, 4, 5, 104, 105. But the purpose of ID is to identify the record, not to give any meaning like creation time. If you need creation time, just add a column that means creation time and sort by it when you need it.
2. You can use *autoincrement* column type, if you use databases MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: "nextval" or autoincrement -->wont applicable here as this is a simplified version of the problem. actual problem has some complex task. Idea is to have consistency.

Comment: @SiddharthaSadhukhan: You asked about *race condition*. Sequences solve it. What you are asking now, is a different thing. Post another question an describe what your actual goal is. If it is idempotency, again explain *why* idempotency, because may be you have *another* reason, and to reach that *another* reason you think idempotency can help.

Comment: Please find the update. Operation could be anything but it should provide consistency

Comment: 1) @SiddharthaSadhukhan: *"Idea is to have consistency."* - You still have not defined, what do you mean by consistency. I don't see any inconsistency on using sequences.

Comment: 2) @SiddharthaSadhukhan: If you *real* goal that you don't name is to have IDs in some particular order depending on messages in the queue, you *will not reach it* by a simple approach. Why not? Because if service instance A receives a message earlier than service instance B, A can hang for some time (because OS is swapping, or because a CPU switched to another thread or another process for some time and A is being not executed for some time, because CPU has high load and A receives relatively small part of its power, etc.)...

Comment: @SiddharthaSadhukhan: ... Thus, even the queue has passed an event to A *before* passing next event to B, A can be hanging and have not yet called database, where as B has received an event, incremented ID from 1 to 2 and saved the even successfully. And A receives and starts processing a message actually *after* B already saved the next event. Thus, messages/events that were created/sent earlier can have bigger IDs than messages/events created/sent later. Depending on the factors named above, B can process event *multiple* messages before A processes a single event...

Comment: @SiddharthaSadhukhan: ... Thus, you cannot guarantee that IDs say anything about time of messages/events. Messages/events that occurred later can have IDs smaller that messages/events that occurred earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can leverage the RDBMS to do the needful.
Essentially you are leveraging the atomicity property of the ACID properties of the RDBMS.
Note: The following is pseudo-SQL.

For

```
if no record found
   state <- 'QUEUED'
   count <- 0
```

Do an insert like

```
Insert in Table ...
id = ..., state = ..., cout = ....
Where Id = ...
```

If there is no row in the table for the Id, it will be successful, and you are done.

For

```
if state == 'QUEUED' and count == 5
   state <- 'INPROGRESS'
```

Do an update like

```
Update Table ... state = 'INPROGESS'
Where Id = ... and count = 5
```

Again success is what tells you are done

For

```
if state == 'QUEUED' and count < 5
   count <- count + 1
```

Do an update like

```
Update Table 
SET count = count + 1
where count < 5 and Id = ...
```

Again success ...

This is the easy part. However, the more difficult question is, how to deal with the situation when a message is not deleted or times out and shows up to be processed again.